# Counterexample for conjugate rules in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[4]{2}]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, complex-numbers

We all know that, in a field, such as $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ or $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[4]{2}]$, conjugate properties that as $ \overline {u \cdot v} = \overline {u} \cdot \overline {v} $ hold. Furthermore, consider the following. If $v=\overline{u}$, the conjugate of $u$, then we have $$ \left( u \overline {u} \right) \cdot \overline {\left( u \overline {u} \right)} = u \cdot \overline {u} \cdot \overline {u} u = \left( u \cdot \overline {u} \right)^2. $$But, let $u=1+\sqrt[4]{2}$. Now, this does not hold. What went wrong?

Comment: $u=\bar{u}$, so both expressions are just $u^4$. What's going wrong? Might it be the idea that $\bar{u}=1-\sqrt[4]{2}$? Also, these rings are not fields - just try to invert $2$.

Comment: Do the rings have to be fields for the conjugate properties to hold?

Comment: There are to things that are called conjugates that are getting mixed here. One is complex conjugate, and another is conjugates, as the other roots of the minimal polynomial (or a Galois automorphism acting on the ). Complex conjugate is a particular case $i$ goes to $-i$, which is the other root in the minimal polynomial $x^2+1$. But the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[4]{2}$ is $x^4-2$, which has another 3 roots, not only $-\sqrt[4]{2}$. We can have the automorphism that changes $\sqrt[4]{2}$ to its opposite, but then you have to be careful in computing how it acts in other numbers.

Comment: I think you might have computed $u\overline{u}$ and got $1-\sqrt{2}$ but then you may have computed the conjugate of this as $1+\sqrt{2}$. But this is not the case. The automorphism that changes $\sqrt[4]{2}$ to $-\sqrt[4]{2}$ actually leaves $1-\sqrt{2}$ invariant.

Comment: Therefore you get $u\overline{u}=1-\sqrt{2}$, $\overline{u\overline{u}}=1-\sqrt{2}$ and then the product of these is $(1-\sqrt{2})^2=(u\overline{u})^2$.

Comment: Ah, excellent! This is what I was looking for. See, right now, I am trying to find a polynomial $P(x)$ with rational coefficients such that $ \dfrac {1}{1+\sqrt[4]{2}} $ is a root and I started by going back to the square root case, instead of the fourth-root. And I said: oh, if $\dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}$ is a root, then so is $\dfrac{1}{1-\sqrt{2}}$, and this logic worked and it turned out that I got $ x^2 - 2x - 1 $. 

Taking this for $4$ is slightly difficult, not to mention the third root.



Also, you should convert your coments into an answer. you deserve upvotes there. :P

Comment: Then you didn't really show your work. }:) You didn't show how you had computed the conjugate of $u\overline{u}$. I had to guess the problem was there. Just joking. If you have that $r$ is a root of the polynomial $P(x)=(x-r)Q(x)$, then $1/r$ is going to be a root of the polynomial $x^{d}P(1/x)=(1-rx)r^{d-1}Q(1/x)$, where $d$ is the degree of $P$. This will help you find the polynomial of $1-\sqrt[4]{2}$ and also for cubic roots.

Comment: @ABC Thanks a lot! Do you have a proof for that useful fact? Please, really. Post these as one compiled answer. I really need to reward you for this. I'm starting a bounty on this just so that I can give you a bunch of reputation.